# why this heap sort code fails for some input array

Tags: sorting, data-structures, heap, heapsort, binary-heap

can any body please tell me whats wrong in this code? i have already spent almost 1 day behind this to find out whats wrong in this. this heap sort code fails for some input.

> i.e. for input array arr = {1,5,2,4,3,6,0,7,9,8}.
> this code should print
> {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0} but this code gives {5,9,8,7,6,4,3,2,1,0}

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


void printarr(int *arr,int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}


void heapify(int *arr,int i,int n)
{
    int max=i;
    
    if(arr[max]<arr[(2*i)+1] && (2*i)+1<=n)
    max=(2*i)+1;
    
    if(arr[max]<arr[(2*i)+2] && (2*i)+2<=n)
    max=(2*i)+2;
    
    if(i!=max)
    {
        swap(arr[max],arr[i]);
        heapify(arr,max,n);
    }
}


void buildheap(int *arr,int i,int j)
{   
    for(;i<=(i+j)/2;i++)
    heapify(arr,i,j);
}


int* heapsort(int *arr,int i,int n)
{
    buildheap(arr,0,n-1);
    
    int *b,index=0;
    b=new int[n];

    while(n>=i)
    {   
        b[index++]=arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[n--];
        heapify(arr,i,n);   
    }
    return b;
}


int main()
{
    int *arr,n;
    cout<<"how many elements?"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"enter elements : "<<endl;
    arr=new int [n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>arr[i];
    

    arr=heapsort(arr,0,n-1);
    
    printarr(arr,n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 errors

1. You should first check out of bound condition and then compare.

   - Change `if(arr[max]<arr[(2*i)+1] && (2*i)+1<=n) max=(2*i)+1;`
   - To `if((2*i)+1<=n && arr[max]<arr[(2*i)+1])`
2. If you are building a heap, You run loop like this. Because of what you have written in heapify

   - Change  `void buildheap(int *arr,int i,int j) { for(;i<=(i+j)/2;i++) heapify(arr,i,j); }`
   - To `void buildheap(int *arr,int i,int j) { for(i = j/2; i >= 0;i--) heapify(arr,i,j);}`

Final Code

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


void printarr(int *arr,int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}


void heapify(int *arr,int i,int n)
{
    int max=i;
    
    
    max=(2*i)+1;
    
    if((2*i)+2<=n && arr[max]<arr[(2*i)+2])
    max=(2*i)+2;
    
    if(i!=max)
    {
        swap(arr[max],arr[i]);
        heapify(arr,max,n);
    }
}


void buildheap(int *arr,int i,int j)
{   
    for(i = j/2; i >= 0;i--)
    heapify(arr,i,j);
}


int* heapsort(int *arr,int i,int n)
{
    buildheap(arr,0,n-1);
    
    int *b,index=0;
    b=new int[n];

    while(n>=i)
    {   
        b[index++]=arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[n--];
        heapify(arr,i,n);   
    }
    return b;
}


int main()
{
    int *arr,n;
    cout<<"how many elements?"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"enter elements : "<<endl;
    arr=new int [n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>arr[i];
    

    arr=heapsort(arr,0,n-1);
    
    printarr(arr,n-1);
}
```